# Implementing a stack to use backtracking for struct

Tags: c, struct, backtracking, robot

This is a program that enables a Robot to follow black lines through a "maze". The maze is made of 7x7 black lines with a entry line leading through it. There can be empty squares and lines leading nowhere. where the black lines meet there is a white square.

The idea is to save these squares in a struct and make the robot run through the maze and save the individual structs in a stack.

I want to do this so that the robot can find the way back through backtracking.

```
void push(int value ){
if(top ==49){ //uncertain what to write here 
} else{
    top = top+1;
    a[top] = value;
}

int pop(){

if(top ==-1){
    return -234;
}else{

    int r = a[top];
    top = top-1;
    return r;
   }
 }
```

I'm uncertain how make this work together with this

```
typedef struct proxy {
int edges[4];
int visited;
int exists;
int token;
} proxy;

int main() {

   /* This part is to make simulation work, idea is to start in the middle
      an 14x14, because that allows us to go in any direction. 
      the arrays are the values that the simulation gives back. 
      This seems to work even though it's not pretty. */

   static int x = 7; 
   static int y = 7;
   static int zaehler = 0;  //Zähler für Rundenbegrenzung
   int Ary[14][14];
   int hilfN, hilfO, hilfS, hilfW;
   int i,j;
   int N[8] = {16, 48, 80, 112, 144, 176, 208, 240};
   int O[8] = {128, 144, 160, 176, 192, 208, 224, 240};
   int S[8] = {32, 48, 96, 112, 160, 176, 224, 240};
   int W[8] = {64, 80, 96, 112, 192, 208, 224, 240};
   int Intersec = Robot_GetIntersections();
   int myRobot_Move(x,y){
   return Robot_Move(x-7,y-7);
}
for(i= 0; i < 14; i++){

    for(j= 0; j < 14; j++){
        Ary[i][j] = 0;
        }
}

myRobot_Move(x,y);

while (x < 14 && y < 14) {
Intersec = Robot_GetIntersections();
Ary[x][y] = Intersec;

for (hilfN=0; hilfN<8; hilfN++){
    if(N[hilfN] == Intersec){
        if(Ary[x][y+1] == 0){
            y++;
            myRobot_Move(x,y);
        }
    }
}
//Osten
for (hilfO=0; hilfO<8; hilfO++){
        if(O[hilfO] == Intersec){
            if(Ary[x+1][y] == 0){
                x++;
                myRobot_Move(x,y);
            }
        }
    }
//Süden
for (i=0; i<8; i++){
        if(S[i] == Intersec){
            if(Ary[x][y-1] == 0){
                y--;
                myRobot_Move(x,y);
            }
        }
    }
//Westen
for (i=0; i<8; i++){
            if(W[i] == Intersec){
                if(Ary[x-1][y] == 0){
                x--;
                myRobot_Move(x,y);
            }
        }
    }

if (Ary[x][y+1] && Ary[x+1][y] && Ary[x][y-1] && Ary[x-1][y] > 0){
    break;
    printf("End");
   }
 }


return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your stack `a` to save `struct proxy`s instead of `int`s, change the presumed `int a[50];` to `proxy a[50];` and the functions `push()` and `pop()` as follows:

```
void push(proxy value)
{
    if (top == 49) puts("'a' stack overflow"), exit(1);
    else a[++top] = value;
}

proxy pop()
{
    if (top == -1) return (proxy){-234};
    else return a[top--];
}
```